# TYPO3 v10 Migration of config.persistence.classes with properties not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I'm currently upgrading from TYPO3 9 to 10 and already changed the persitence mapping like it is descriped here: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87623-ReplaceConfigpersistenceclassesTyposcriptConfiguration.html

The mapping of the model through the tablename works fine, however the columns are not mapped. All fields are null except the uid.

Old Mapping:

```
WS\Shop\Domain\Model\Booking { 
    mapping { 
        tableName = tx_cart_domain_model_checkout 
        columns { 
            uuid.mapOnProperty = uuid 
            creation_timestamp.mapOnProperty = creationTimestamp
            lastedit_timestamp.mapOnProperty = lasteditTimestamp 
            ...
        } 
    } 
}
```

New Mapping:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

return [
    \WS\Shop\Domain\Model\Booking::class => [
        'tableName' => 'tx_cart_domain_model_checkout',
        'properties' => [
            'uuid' => [
                'fieldName' => 'uuid'
            ],
            'creationTimestamp' => [
                'fieldName' => 'creation_timestamp'
            ],
            'lasteditTimestamp' => [
                'fieldName' => 'lastedit_timestamp'
            ],
            ...
        ],
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging *DataMapFactory.php* I found out that you have to create a TCA file for the table (in my case *tx_cart_domain_model_checkout.php*):

```php
<?php
return [
    'columns' => [
        'uuid' => [],
        'creation_timestamp' => [],
        'lastedit_timestamp' => []
    ]
];
```